# ¿Cómo eliminar elementos repetidos de una columna conservando datos?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

Tengo un archivo con informacion de este tipo:

```
0.0,valor1
0.1,valor2
0.2,valor3
0.0,valor4
0.1,valor5
0.2,valor6
```

Lo que intento hacer es eliminar los elementos repetidos de la primer columna pero conservando la información de la columna dos agregándolos como una nueva columna. Es decir que quiero obtener:

```
0.0,valor1,valor4
0.1,valor2,valor5
0.2,valor3,valor6
```

Intente hacer manipulando diccionarios de la siguiente manera

```
with open("file.dat") as archivo:
    datos = {}
    for linea in archivo:
            if linea != "\n":
                   linea_limpia = linea
            tiempo, _ = linea_limpia.rstrip("\n").split(" ")
            if tiempo not in datos:
                   datos[tiempo] = linea_limpia.rstrip("\n")
datos = list(datos.values())
```

Lo que no pude es agregar los valores de la columna 2.

Answer (score 1):

Esta clase de problemas las puedes resolver con un diccionario. La llave es el tiempo (0.0, 0.1, 0.2) y el valor asociado es la lista de valores (valor1, valor2, ...).

Para construir el diccionario vas leyendo linea a linea el archivo y recuperando el tiempo y el valor. Con eso actualizadas tu diccionario asi:

```
for linea in archivo:
    tiempo, valor = linea.rstrip().split(",")
    datos[tiempo].append(valor)
```

Extraer el tiempo y valor del archivo es más simple de lo que hiciste, como podrás apreciar.

Vamos a ocupar `defaultdict` para crear un diccionario con valor por *default*. Eso significa que si tratamos de acceder a una llave que no existe, el `defaultdict` automáticamente crea la entrada y la puebla con el valor por *default* que dijistes:

```
from collections import defaultdict
datos = defaultdict(list)
```

En este caso, el valor por *default* es una lista (vacia).

Asi, todo se reduce a:

```
from collections import defaultdict
with open("file.dat") as archivo:
    datos = defaultdict(list)
    for linea in archivo:
        tiempo, valor = linea.rstrip().split(",")
        datos[tiempo].append(valor)
```

**Comprobación**

Con este código de prueba

```
for key, value in datos.items():
    print(key, value)
```

obtuvimos

```
0.0 ['valor1', 'valor4']
0.1 ['valor2', 'valor5']
0.2 ['valor3', 'valor6']
```

Comment: Genial! Muchisimas gracias por la respuesta. Soy principiante en python y estuve dando vueltas un rato con esto. Con esto ahora puedo intentar manejar grandes archivos "*.dat"

Comment: Cristian, recuerda aceptar la respuesta si te ha sido de utilidad. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la librería [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/).
Para leer los datos

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("file.dat",sep=",",header=None)
df
     0       1
0  0.0  valor1
1  0.1  valor2
2  0.2  valor3
3  0.0  valor4
4  0.1  valor5
5  0.2  valor6
```

y después agrupamos

```
df.groupby(df.columns[0])[df.columns[1]].apply(list)
0.0    [valor1, valor4]
0.1    [valor2, valor5]
0.2    [valor3, valor6]
```